# BlockingCollection with two consumers getting the same data - is it possible?

Tags: c#, multithreading, graph, producer-consumer, .net-4.8

I have a `BlockingCollection` with one producer and one consumer in my application. The consumer writes the received data to a file. I need to make a real-time graph drawing from this data.

1. Is it possible to run a second consumer that would draw graph with the same data from the collection in parallel?
2. however, is it so that when one consumer takes out the data, the other consumer can no longer access it? In the sense that only one copy of the data can be taken out of the collection?  (it seems to me that this is how this 'buffer' works).
3. in that case, is it a good idea that in this consumer that I have to write data to a file to do at the same time adding this data to the other defined BlockingCollection: `collection2.Add(dataBuffer);`? And then create a consumer2 that will draw the graph? I still just don't know how in this case consumer2 would get to the graph, which would be part of the GUI thread.

```
// -----------------------------------------------------------------
// A method that fetches data from a queue and writes it to a file.
// It works in a dedicated Task.
// -----------------------------------------------------------------
static void Consumer()
{
        while (true)
        {
            foreach (DataBuffer dataBuffer in collection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
            {
                _FileStream.Write(dataBuffer.Buffer, 0, dataBuffer.Length);
                _FileStream.Flush();                    
            }
            
            // adding dataBuffer to the second consumer here?
        }
}
```

---

To be more precise. My question is how to organize such an application in an optimal way, because I have no experience (until a month ago, I had no idea about the existence of BlockingCollection).

At the moment:

- I have `Form` window of the application,
- I have an object in which a Task is started, which receives data from an external device,
- after receiving the data, an Event is generated, with which I pass the received data,
- I have another object in which a Handler for this Event runs, and in this Handler the data is taken from the argument and is added to the BlockingCollection,
- I have the consumer Task running, which saves the received to a file.

Now I also need to add drawing an overview chart from the same data as it goes to the file and I am wondering how to do it.

Comment: The `BlockingCollection<T>` can have multiple consumers, but each message is delivered to only one consumer. Are you asking if it's a good idea to have two collections, one for each consumer, so that both consumers can receive all the items?

Comment: Yes, my target is .NET Framework 4.8 Windows Application. I've made edit to clarify what I mean.

Comment: Rather than thinking about building this out of blocking collections, have you looked at the [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library)? That lets you model a pipeline and can include a BroadcastBlock that sends messages on to multiple consumers.

Comment: I suggest to use the publish/subscriber pattern.Eventually use a library like [MediatR](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MediatR/9.0.0) (since version 9.0.0 is available for .NET Framework). This blog could be useful to understand the use of such a tool [CQRS and MediatR in ASP.NET Core](https://code-maze.com/cqrs-mediatr-in-aspnet-core/).

Comment: Don't use MediatR. It was built for a completely different scenario. CQRS has nothing to do with concurrency or pub/sub at the thread level

Comment: .NET already has higher-level constructs for pub/sub and dataflow pipelines. TPL Dataflow is a high-level ... dataflow ... libary that allows you to build a pipeline of processing blocks that only care about processing individual messages. The Dataflow classes take care of workers, buffering, preserving orders

Comment: At a lower level, Channels are an asynchronous concurrent collection meant for pub/sub scenarios among others. Instead of blocking while trying to receive something you can use `await channel.ReaderReadAsync()` or even `await foreach(var msg in channel.Reader.ReadAllAsync())`. Message order is preserved but actually processing the messages is up the the developer.

Comment: What is this overview chart that has to be drawn? Is it a UI control? If yes, is it redrawn from scratch each time a new piece of data is arriving?

Comment: Let's say my data contains measurements from 10 different sensors. A data packet received at one time may contain 200 measurement points: `sensor1_time1, sensor2_time1, sensor3_time1, [...], sensor1_time2, sensor2_time2, sensor3_time3, [...], sensor1_time20, sensor2_time20, sensor3_time20 [...]` Of course, with new packets I get more data. In the app, I would like to choose, e.g. to draw online in the UI a graph of the values of the last, current 512 samples for sensor #3. So with each received data packet, I need to extract the values for the selected sensor and draw them on the graph.

Comment: Doesn't the graph need to be drawn on the UI thread?

Comment: Yes, it must. It is my puzzle how to do it if I have data received in another thread - the earliest data is available in this receiving Handler. And how to draw such a chart, so that at the same time also the UI is responsive, so as not to freeze it, because I also have some buttons in it, etc.

Comment: Have you considered having a UI timer (for example a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`) that ticks every second and redraws the graph, with the data that are currently available?